# jUnit tests work in Eclipse, but fail when I run them through ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

I have the following tasks in ant:

```
<target name="init-junit" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.reports.individual}" />
    <property name="running-junit" value="true" />
</target>

<target name="run-tests" depends="init-junit, compile">
    <junit>
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${junit.reports.individual}">
            <fileset dir="${dir.build}" includes="**/*Test*" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>

<target name="compile-reports" depends="run-tests">
    <junitreport todir="${junit.reports}" tofile="junit-report.xml">
        <fileset dir="${junit.reports.individual}" />
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.reports}/html" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

with `${dir.build}` being the directory with all my `.class` files. The jUnit tests work when I run them in eclipse, but fail when I run them through ant (either run through eclipse or terminal); they each throw the following exception:

```
org.fscit.{name of class}
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.fscit.{name of class}
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
```

I have `junit-4.8.2.jar` in my `lib` folder, which is in the classpath with the id, `classpath`, and I have build.xml on my project root directory, with its `basedir` property set to `.`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your classpath ref doesn't look right. I doubt that its actually locating your classes and the error message seems to bear that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the destination directory of your classes in the classpath. You should have `${dir.build}` in your classpath element.

```
<path id="classpath">
<pathelement location="${dir.build}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pathelement task

```
<pathelement location="${dir.build}" />
```

instead of fileset task

```
<fileset dir="${dir.build}" />
```

It works for me (ant version is 1.7.1)